# OpenGL ES get Coordinates of Object

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to make an android application, but to do so I am trying to figure out how to get the (x, y, z) coordinates of an object. How do I do this?

I am really new to OpenGL, so use simple lingo. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL is not a [scene graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph) library. You have to do the bookkeeping yourself.

You give OpenGL buch of vertices/indices/texcoords and it renders them obeying the current render mode, without any clue about the high-level representation of the vertices.

Take a look at the [chopsticks3d](http://code.google.com/p/chopsticks3d/) Android scene graph library to get 'live' example of how its done.